# Trying to save a video into a folder but it show 0 KB.What is the problem?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save video using VideoCapture object in openCv using python. But the video is saved as 'output.avi' but its size is showing as 0 KB. Need your help, not able to find out the error.

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\farhana\\Tom.und.Jerry.Piraten.auf.Schatzsuche.mp4")

    out = cv2.VideoWriter("C:\\farhana\\output.avi", -1, 20.0, (640,480))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

            out.write(frame)

            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("C:\\farhana\\output.avi", -1, 20.0, (640,480))
```

To:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("C:\\farhana\\output.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 20.0, (640,480))
```

The second argument in cv2.VideoWriter() should be the [fourcc code](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) of the codec to be used in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that 'frame' size is must be equal to the size that you specified in cv2.VideoWriter.Thus try:

`frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,480)); out.write(frame)`